# Python Basemap drawgreatcircle has a gap in the path

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am seeing some strange basemap behaviour. It draws a great circle with a gap in it.

Here is the code to draw a great circle from Vancouver to London:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_map():
    bg_color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    coast_color = (204/255.0, 0.8, 153/255.0, 0.7)
    country_color = (204/255.0, 0.8, 153/255.0, 0.2)
    path_color = (204/255.0, 0.2, 153/255.0, 0.6)

    dep_lat, dep_lon = 51.470020, -0.454295
    arr_lat, arr_lon = 49.193901, -123.183998

    plt.figure()

    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-130.,llcrnrlat=40.,urcrnrlon=10.,urcrnrlat=70.,\
            rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
            resolution='l',projection='merc',\
            lat_0=40.,lon_0=-20.,lat_ts=20.)
    m.drawcoastlines(color=coast_color, linewidth=1.0)
    m.fillcontinents(color=bg_color, lake_color=bg_color)
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color=bg_color)
    m.drawgreatcircle(dep_lon, dep_lat,arr_lon, arr_lat,
                      linewidth=2.0, color=path_color)

    plt.savefig('routes.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_map()
```

And here is the result:[image]

The path object returned by drawgreatcircle contains many NANs where the gap is:

```
...
[10665759.64101299,  4404955.44856027],
[10474119.01096945,  4511711.30524047],
[              nan,               nan],
[              nan,               nan],
...
[              nan,               nan],
[              nan,               nan],
[ 4228670.53408886,  4599991.37541622],
[ 4031731.93039374,  4496703.65196268],
[ 3840974.7826069 ,  4389405.80623971],
...
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I get with your code an error message `AttributeError: can't set attribute` in the line `m.drawgreatcircle...`.

Comment: I think that is a version issue. I am using matplotlib v3.0.2. I get that error with 3.0.1.

Comment: Indeed. Well, that was of no help for you.

Comment: While there is no solution, why don't you use other projection instead of `'merc'`. Even `'cyl'` should give you a good plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to workaround the issue you face when use `merc` (Mercator) projection to compute points at high latitude is using other projection that works. But if you insist on using Mercator to plot such high-latitude points, you may need to combine 2 methods. Here I use `cyl` (no projection) to plot greatcircle arc. Then, extract its coordinates, and finally, use the coordinates to plot the greatcircle path on `merc` projection.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()

# use 'cyl' projection to get greatcircle path
# some of the parameters are ignored dummies
m0 = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-130.,llcrnrlat=40.,urcrnrlon=10.,urcrnrlat=70., \
        rsphere=(6378137.00, 6356752.3142), \
        resolution='l', projection='cyl', \
        lat_0=40., lon_0=-20., lat_ts=20.)

dep_lat, dep_lon = 51.470020, -0.454295
arr_lat, arr_lon = 49.193901, -123.183998
# draw greatcircle and grab it
gcc = m0.drawgreatcircle(dep_lon, dep_lat,arr_lon, arr_lat, del_s=100.0, \
                      linewidth=2.0, color='None')
ax0 = fig.gca()
ax0.set_visible(False)   # suppress the plot of 'cyl' projection

# get list of long-lat for greatcircle plot later
xys = gcc[0].get_xydata()

def plot_map():
    bg_color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    coast_color = (204/255.0, 0.8, 153/255.0, 0.7)
    country_color = (204/255.0, 0.8, 153/255.0, 0.2)
    path_color = (204/255.0, 0.2, 153/255.0, 0.6)

    plt.figure(figsize=[10, 6])

    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-130.,llcrnrlat=40.,urcrnrlon=10.,urcrnrlat=70., \
            rsphere=(6378137.00, 6356752.3142), \
            resolution='l', projection='merc', \
            lat_0=40., lon_0=-20., lat_ts=20.)

    m.drawcoastlines(color=coast_color, linewidth=1.0)
    m.fillcontinents(color=bg_color, lake_color=bg_color)
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color=bg_color)

    # problematic code ...
    # m.drawgreatcircle(dep_lon, dep_lat,arr_lon, arr_lat, del_s=100.0, \
    #                 linewidth=2.0, color=path_color)

    # plot path on the map with coordinates obtained earlier
    m.plot(xys[:,0], xys[:,1], latlon=True)

    plt.savefig('routes.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_map()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]